# receive json response in php

Tags: php, json

I have a url like this

localhost/handikap/insert/index.php?json={"id":123456}

and I want to get the json response out of it while I have written a code like this

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

but this is not returning anything Please help me out

Comment: If you are getting response from $_GET then you can use $data= json_decode($_GET['json']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GET method

```
$data = $_GET['json'];
$data = json_decode();
print_r($data);
```

If you are using POST method

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data =  (array)json_decode($data,true);
```